# NLog Mail target fails when used in a web application

Tags: email, web-config, target, nlog

I've just upgraded NLog in my NancyFx web application to version 4.3.2 and the app now throws an error the first time it tries to get a Logger instance.  The error being thrown is:

> exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe

I've narrowed the problem down to the NLog Mail target, which (according to its source) is attempting to read:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp")
>   as SmtpSection

...to try to find the mail setting from the app's web.config file.  The OpenExeConfiguration is expecting an app.exe.config file, which doesn't exist for a web app.

So, my question is how do I tell NLog where to find the web.config file, or better still, how can I tell NLog not to bother looking in the web.config file at all as I'm not storing any mail settings there?

Here's my target xml in nlog.config:

```
<target xsi:type="Mail"
        name="smtplog"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
        useSystemNetMailSettings="false"
        to="test-to@test.com"
        from="test-from@test.com"
        smtpUserName="USERNAME"
        enableSsl="True"
        smtpPassword="PASSWORD"
        smtpAuthentication="Basic"
        smtpServer="smtp.sendgrid.net"
        smtpPort="587" />
```

If I remove the target then the app loads fine.

ps this was working just fine with the earlier version of NLog I was using (v2.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in NLog 4.3.2 and has been fixed in 4.3.3